# Tkinter and execute a python file as in IDLE

Tags: python, cmd, tkinter, execute

I've recently discovered Tkinter and its uses, but it only works when we run it from IDLE (file > open > F5)

I'd like to use it from the cmd window but it doesn't open the tkinter window and canevas

is there any way to open a python file from the cmd window as IDLE would have done it ?

Comment: There's nothing special you need to do. From the prompt just type `python /path/to/program.py`. Have you tried that? If that "doesn't work" describe what "doesn't work" means. Does it crash? Does it silently exit? Does it run, but no window appears?

Comment: It's more common to have the reverse problem because IDLE uses `Tkinter` itself internally.  One possibility is that your code assumes something in `Tkinter` is initialized, but that's only true when it is run from IDLE. Exactly what error messages are you getting?

Comment: @martineau By default, and for perhaps a decade, IDLE executes code in a separate process that does not usually use tkinter.  It does, however, import tkinter even when not needed, and this can have effect in allowing code to run.  (I plan to fix this to only import tkinter when needed, after user code has started.)

Comment: @TerryJanReedy: Truth be told, I haven't used IDLE much since I first started using Python (roughly the same time as you) and Guido first released it. It's own use of `tkinter` was one of the main reasons I quickly switched to something else. As a CPython core developer focused on IDLE, I suggest you make removing any interactions it was with the environment the user program runs in more of a priority, otherwise its usefulness as an Integrated DeveLopment Environment will forever be greatly compromised (IMHO), especially for Python newbies — who are its most likely users.

Answer (score 1):

IDLE executes a file nearly the same as `python -i path/file.py` -- notice the `-i`.  The result is that tkinter windows are left on screen, and can be interacted with, after file.py execution stops. This is really handy for development.  You likely have to add `-i` to your command line (if still developing), or add `root.mainloop()` (or the equivalent) at the end of your program.  (There are parts of tkinter that do not work with .mainloop omitted, even in IDLE, but many part do.)

In 3.x, it is possible to write an import that works in IDLE and fails at the command line.  But you did not mention getting an ImportError traceback.

If neither of these is your problem, then create and post a truly [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), along with answers to Bryan's questions.